# How to display nested array in extjs grid cell

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I'm trying to loop through a nested json array to display values in a grid cell (using extjs 6.0).

Here is the column in the view:

```
{
    header: 'Participants',
    dataIndex: 'participants'   
},
```

The model:

```
Ext.define('App.model.Event', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [

        { name: 'eventTypeName', type: 'auto', mapping: 'eventType.eventType' },

        // this only grabs the first object in the list....how to grab all?
        { name: 'participants', type: 'auto', mapping: 'participants[0].participantName' },


    ]
});
```

And the json:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "events" : [ {
      "participants" : [ {
        "participantId" : 1,
        "participantName" : "name1"
      }, {
        "participantId" : 2,
        "participantName" : "name2"
      }, {
        "participantId" : 3,
        "participantName" : "name3"
      } ],

    }
  }
}
```

The rows in the grid are the events, and each event row will have multiple participants that I want to display in a cell. How can all of the participant names be displayed in a single cell?

I've tried something similar to this post using the hasMany method, to no avail: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?205509-Displaying-a-hasMany-model-relationship-in-a-Grid&p=822648&viewfull=1#post822648

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want it to look like in the cell? Do you just want a comma-separated list of the participant names?

Comment: Yes, a comma-separated list of names would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display special content in a cell, then you'll need to implement a [renderer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-modern/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer). In the renderer function, you would iterate over your participants for the current row, building and returning an HTML string based on what you want that cell to look like.

Comment: You're right. Here's my working renderer based on your tip:  renderer: function(value, p, r) {
  {
   if (r.data.participants) {
    var list = [];
    for (i = 0; i < r.data.participants.length; i++) {
      list.push(' ' + r.data.participants[i].participantName )
    }
    return list
   }
  }
  
 }